# Exporting from blender to unity with texture

Tags: texturing, unity

I followed this udemy course to build a character in blender and I'm trying to export it with the textures into unity, for some reason it won't export the textures with the model, added some photos of what Iv'e already tried.
Any advice will be helpful,
Thanks!!
[image: Model with texture]

[image: Exporting settings]

[image: Unity]

[image: Unity2]

Comment: You need to import the images into unity manually and then add them to the material.

Comment: How do I export the images from blender ?

Comment: Open the image in an image editor, press ALT+S or SHIT+ALT+S to save the image externally. But if you already have the images on your drive, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the thing is there is no image, it's combined of many settings as seen in the image above. Maybe I should bake it?

Comment: I see 3 images in your screenshot : Jean.jpg, PantsN(?) and Pants_spec but if those are not the ones you need and you want your procedural textures to be taken to Unity, you may need to bake it, indeed.

Comment: Solved: I used baking to get the textures on the UV's